# How to get the name of the currently executed js-file?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jscript

I use the following construction for an offline routine (using Notepad++ as editor):

1) Execute `"test.bat"`.

2) `"test.bat"` executes consecutively the list: *"C:\test.exe" C:\abc_"date".jsp* with one line per "date" (YYMMDD)

3) Up to now each `abc_"date".jsp` contains two js-files: (1) *date.js* which contains nothing but the var DATE = "date", however the date is required to initilise the main.js and (2) `*main.js*` which contains the actual routine

Is there a way to read out the date directly from the jsp-file (as substring of the name) within `main.js`? (To avoid the extra `date.js` files.)

Comment: You could add the DATE variable to the main.js file.

Comment: In my case, the main.js is a unique file (actually a set of 4) which contains the global functionality and the main function. However, for each .jsp-file I require another setting of var DATE. Up to now a GNU R routine is creating all required date.js files. I would not win much when the GNU R routine is instead creating 1000 slightly different main.js.